# My code is very inefficient for this simple Linq usage

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following method that is supposed to parse information from an XML response and return a collection of users.

I've opted into creating a Friend class and returning a `List<Friend>` to the calling method.

Here's what I have so far, but I noticed that the ids.ToList().Count method parses every single id element to a List, then does it again in the for conditional. It's just super ineffective.

```
public List<Friend> FindFriends()
{
    List<Friend> friendList = new List<Friend>();

    var friends = doc.Element("ipb").Element("profile").Element("friends").Elements("user");
    var ids = from fr in friends
              select fr.Element("id").Value;

    var names = from fr in friends
                select fr.Element("name").Value;

    var urls = from fr in friends
                select fr.Element("url").Value;

    var photos = from fr in friends
                select fr.Element("photo").Value;

    if (ids.ToList().Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.ToList().Count; i++)
        {
            Friend buddy = new Friend();
            buddy.ID = ids.ToList()[i];
            buddy.Name = names.ToList()[i];
            buddy.URL = urls.ToList()[i];
            buddy.Photo = photos.ToList()[i];

            friendList.Add(buddy);
        }
    }            

    return friendList;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First question - do you have to return a `List<Friend>`? Can you return an `IEnumerable<Friend>` instead? If so, performance gets a lot better:

```
IEnumerable<Friend> FindFriends()
{
    return doc.Descendants("user").Select(user => new Friend {
        ID = user.Element("id").Value,
        Name = user.Element("name").Value,
        Url = user.Element("url").Value,
        Photo = user.Element("photo").Value
    });
}
```

Rather than actually creating new buckets and stuffing values into them, this creates a **projection**, or a new object that simply contains all of the logic for *how* to create the new Friend objects without actually creating them. They get created when the caller eventually starts to `foreach` over the IEnumerable. This is called "deferred execution".

This also makes one assumption - All the `<user>` nodes in your XML fragment are friends. If that isn't true, the first part of the XML selection might need to be a *little* more complex.

And as @anon points out, even if you do need to return a `List<Friend>` for some reason not obvious from the information you've provided, you can just call `.ToList()` at the end of the return statement. This will just execute the projection I described above straight into a new bucket, so you only ever create one.

Comment: Even if they have to return a list, calling `ToList()` on this is going to be better than what they're doing now.

Comment: I don't have to return a List, I'm just used to using it. I always seem to forget about IEnumarable. Thank you, this code is just wonderful. I'll test it out and see if it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the separate ids/names/urls/photos variables?  Combine it all.  You can eliminate the ToList() call if you don't need a List.

```
List<Friend> friendList = (from f in doc.Element("ipb").Element("profile").Element("friends").Elements("user")
                          select new Friend() { 
                                                 ID = f.Element("id").Value, 
                                                 Name = f.Element("name").Value,
                                                 URL = f.Element("url").Value,
                                                 Photo = f.Element("photo").Value
                                 }).ToList();

return friendList;
```